# How to calculate an integral with a change parameter and record every result as a sequence in R?

Tags: r, sequence, integral

I have an integral with a change parameter (y) as follows.

```
y <- seq(1,2,0.01)
integrand_1 <- function(t){
  
  A1 <- 30*(y*30^(1/2)-t)^2
  A2 <- (dnorm(t+30^(1/2))+dnorm(t-30^(1/2)))
  
  return(pchisq(A1, 30)*A2)
}
W <- integrate( f = integrand_1, 
                   lower = 0, 
                   upper = y*30^(1/2)
)

W <- W$value
W
```

However, the integral cannot allow a sequence parameter to import it.

How can I obtain the outcomes with the sequence parameter and make the outcomes be a sequence (W)?

Many thanks to anyone who can provide a solution.

Comment: Is `y` in `integrand_1` supposed to be the same as the scaled `upper` argument passed to `integrate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, we need to make a couple of small changes to your code.

1. We know that `integrate`'s first argument has to be numeric. In your example: `t`. However, we also have `y`, which has to be passed to the function as well. So our new function is:

```
integrand <- function(t, y) {
  a1 <- 30 * (y * 30 ^ (1 / 2) - t) ^ 2
  a2 <- (dnorm(t + 30 ^ (1 / 2)) + dnorm(t - 30 ^ (1 / 2)))
  
  pchisq(a1, 30) * a2
}
```

Since we cannot pass a vector along to integrate, but still need to evaluate it for all values of `y`, I wrap it in a `lapply()` expression, which will return a list with the value of the integral for each value of `Y`.

```
# Let's call the vector of Y values capital Y and elements of this lower-case y
Y <- seq(1, 2, 0.01)

# Use the lapply to evaluate the integral for each y
W_list <- lapply(Y, function(y) {
  integrate(
    f = integrand, 
    lower = 0, 
    upper = y * 30 ^ (1 / 2),
    y = y # NOTE: This is where I pass the additional y argument to integrand inside integrate
  )
})
```

Lastly, we extract the values and combine them into a vector

```
W <- do.call(c, lapply(W_list, function(w) w$value))
```

W is now the same length as Y and contains values:

```
[1] 0.1626543 0.1763727 0.1908012 0.2059319 0.2217521
[6] 0.2382447
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your professional and insightful response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that [edsandorf's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65805049/5861244) version of the integrand is correct, you can use this combination of `mapply` and `sapply`:

```
integrand <- function(t, y){
  A1 <- 30*(y*30^(1/2)-t)^2
  A2 <- (dnorm(t+30^(1/2))+dnorm(t-30^(1/2)))
  
  return(pchisq(A1, 30)*A2)
}
res <- mapply(integrate, upper = y*30^(1/2), y = y, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, 
              MoreArgs = list(f = integrand, lower = 0))
sapply(res, `[[`, "value")
#R>   [1] 0.1627 0.1764 0.1908 0.2059 0.2218 0.2382 0.2554 0.2732 0.2915 0.3104 0.3299 0.3498 0.3701 0.3908 0.4118 0.4330 0.4545 0.4761
#R>  [19] 0.4977 0.5194 0.5410 0.5625 0.5838 0.6048 0.6256 0.6460 0.6660 0.6855 0.7045 0.7230 0.7409 0.7582 0.7748 0.7908 0.8061 0.8206
#R>  [37] 0.8345 0.8477 0.8601 0.8718 0.8829 0.8932 0.9029 0.9119 0.9202 0.9280 0.9352 0.9417 0.9478 0.9534 0.9584 0.9630 0.9672 0.9710
#R>  [55] 0.9744 0.9775 0.9802 0.9827 0.9849 0.9868 0.9886 0.9901 0.9914 0.9926 0.9937 0.9946 0.9954 0.9960 0.9966 0.9971 0.9976 0.9980
#R>  [73] 0.9983 0.9986 0.9988 0.9990 0.9992 0.9993 0.9994 0.9995 0.9996 0.9997 0.9997 0.9998 0.9998 0.9999 0.9999 0.9999 0.9999 0.9999
#R>  [91] 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response. This answer does help me a lot.